# Use appropriate calendar profile based on user's geo-location: perl

Tags: perl, calendar

I'm using the delta_workdays() method in my perl script to calculate the number of working days between 2 dates. Currently I'm using the US profile for the calculation and would like to add support for UK as well. Based on user's location, either the US profile will be used or the GB profile. Is there a perl function I can use to fetch user's location and use the appropriate profile?

for e.g.

```
if ($user_location=="US"){  
   my $cal = Date::Calendar->new( $Profiles->{US} );  
}   
elsif($user_location=="GB"){   
   my $cal = Date::Calendar->new( $Profiles->{GB} );   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might ask the system for the timezone:

```
use POSIX;
$user_location = strftime '%Z', localtime;
```

For the US, you will probably get PDT, MDT, MST, CDT, and EDT (and maybe even HST, HADT, and AKDT). UK should be GMT.

BTW, for string comparison, use `eq` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch it from what? I know of no system that knows its user resides in Florida (`US-FL`), much less that they work there. It's definitely wouldn't work for anyone on Windows (which only knows of country). The user will have to specify it.